# Rotating x axis labels in R for barplot

Tags: r, graph, plot, bar-chart, axis-labels

I am trying to get the x axis labels to be rotated 45 degrees on a barplot with no luck. This is the code I have below:

```
barplot(((data1[,1] - average)/average) * 100,
        srt       = 45,
        adj       = 1,
        xpd       = TRUE,
        names.arg = data1[,2],
        col       = c("#3CA0D0"),
        main      = "Best Lift Time to Vertical Drop Ratios of North American Resorts",
        ylab      = "Normalized Difference",
        yaxt      = 'n',
        cex.names = 0.65,
        cex.lab   = 0.65)
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

EDITED ANSWER PER DAVID'S RESPONSE:

Here's a kind of hackish way.  I'm guessing there's an easier way.  But you could suppress the bar labels and the plot text of the labels by saving the bar positions from `barplot` and do a little tweaking up and down.  Here's an example with the mtcars data set:

```
x <- barplot(table(mtcars$cyl), xaxt="n")
labs <- paste(names(table(mtcars$cyl)), "cylinders")
text(cex=1, x=x-.25, y=-1.25, labs, xpd=TRUE, srt=45)
```

Comment: _caveat_: If you're using `beside = TRUE`, you'll probably want to use `colMeans(x)` instead of just `x` if you want only one label per group.

Answer (score 333):

use optional parameter las=2 .

```
barplot(mytable,main="Car makes",ylab="Freqency",xlab="make",las=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I believe that this should be the accepted answer. Works perfectly using a parameter of the base barplot function used in the question.

Comment: Agreed, this should be the accepted answer. Much more concise solution

Comment: use par(mar=c(15,4,4,2)) to adjust the margins so the vertical labels are not cropped from the figure.

Comment: I personally prefer this approach, but it did not answer the OP's original question:

_I am trying to get the x axis labels to be rotated 45 degrees on a barplot_

Comment: you can see 'make' is covered by labels. How to fix it?

Comment: that 'make' shown below the plot can be removed by adding title = "".

Answer (score 34):

Rotate the x axis labels with angle equal or smaller than 90 degrees using base graphics. Code adapted from the [R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-create-rotated-axis-labels_003f):

```
par(mar = c(7, 4, 2, 2) + 0.2) #add room for the rotated labels

#use mtcars dataset to produce a barplot with qsec colum information
mtcars = mtcars[with(mtcars, order(-qsec)), ] #order mtcars data set by column "qsec"

end_point = 0.5 + nrow(mtcars) + nrow(mtcars) - 1 #this is the line which does the trick (together with barplot "space = 1" parameter)

barplot(mtcars$qsec, col = "grey50", 
        main = "",
        ylab = "mtcars - qsec", ylim = c(0,5 + max(mtcars$qsec)),
        xlab = "",
        xaxt = "n", # Do not plot the default labels
        space = 1)
#rotate 60 degrees (srt = 60)
text(seq(1.5, end_point, by = 2), par("usr")[3]-0.25, 
     srt = 60, adj = 1, xpd = TRUE,
     labels = paste(rownames(mtcars)), cex = 0.65)
```

[image]

Comment: What use `text()`? `axis()` does not work?

Answer (score 15):

You can simply pass your data frame into the following **function**:

```
rotate_x <- function(data, column_to_plot, labels_vec, rot_angle) {
    plt <- barplot(data[[column_to_plot]], col='steelblue', xaxt="n")
    text(plt, par("usr")[3], labels = labels_vec, srt = rot_angle, adj = c(1.1,1.1), xpd = TRUE, cex=0.6) 
}
```

**Usage:**

```
rotate_x(mtcars, 'mpg', row.names(mtcars), 45)
```

[image]

You can change the **rotation angle** of the labels as needed.

Answer (score 10):

You can use ggplot2 to rotate the x-axis label adding an additional layer

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Answer (score 9):

You may use

```
par(las=2) # make label text perpendicular to axis
```

It is written here: http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html

Answer (score 6):

In the documentation of Bar Plots we can read about the additional parameters (`...`) which can be passed to the function call:

```
...    arguments to be passed to/from other methods. For the default method these can 
       include further arguments (such as axes, asp and main) and graphical 
       parameters (see par) which are passed to plot.window(), title() and axis.
```

In the documentation of graphical parameters (documentation of `par`) we can see:

```
las
    numeric in {0,1,2,3}; the style of axis labels.

    0:
      always parallel to the axis [default],

    1:
      always horizontal,

    2:
      always perpendicular to the axis,

    3:
      always vertical.

    Also supported by mtext. Note that string/character rotation via argument srt to par does not affect the axis labels.
```

That is why passing `las=2` makes the labels **perpendicular, although not at 45°**.

Comment: perpendicular is not 45 degrees!

Comment: @Tomas fair enough, I edited the last sentence.

Comment: The point is that it is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Andre Silva's answer works great for me, with one caveat in the "barplot" line:

```
barplot(mtcars$qsec, col="grey50", 
    main="",
    ylab="mtcars - qsec", ylim=c(0,5+max(mtcars$qsec)),
    xlab = "",
    xaxt = "n", 
    space=1)
```

Notice the "xaxt" argument. Without it, the labels are drawn twice, the first time without the 60 degree rotation.

Comment: where is the 45 degree rotation?