# How to get the mean, and, include mean to a plot for numeric data

Tags: r, plot, warnings

I am a novice R user & have reviewed related questions on the site. Although the title of my question has been asked before I am experiencing some additional issues that I am unable to solve.

I was able to *successfully* use R console to make a boxplot with data I imported via .csv that includes some NA values (using `boxplot(Test)`), where Test is the name of my data and includes 3 columns of data with labels with 20 data points each.

But when I tried to calculate mean (by using: `mean(Test)` or try to add it to the successfully made boxplot (by using: `abline(v=mean(Test)`) it gave me the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(Test) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Now when I tried: `sapply(Test, mean, na.rm = TRUE)`, I did get the correct results but they were followed by the warning message:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

All the right calculations comes out when using: `Summary (Test)` without any warning messages. *I am confused as to what the issue is? Any advice would really help please! thank you*

**UPDATE2:**
Thank you for the answer below, worked well.

**UPDATE1:**
Thank you to those who helped below - using     `colMeans(Test, na.rm=TRUE)` returns the means for all my columns. **However**, is it possible to add the mean as a point for each individual column of data into a boxplot of all the data (i.e. all three columns)?  Using     `abline(v=colMeans(Test))` only adds a single line into the whole plot.

***Additional Info:***
When I use: `class(Test)` it returns:

```
[1] "data.frame"
```

Also I checked the type of my data (apologies if I am using any incorrect words) using `sapply(Test, mode)` and it returns "**numeric**" for all 3 columns of my data.

Partial Dataset only

```
a       b       c
0.68    0.68    0.68
0.28    0.28    0.28
0.62    0.62    0.62
0.73    0.73    0.73
```

Comment: For the `mean`, you need to specify the column i.e. `mean(Test[,1])` for getting the mean of first column.  If there are multiple columns, `colMeans(Test)` gives the `mean` of each of the columns.  Can you show an example data

Comment: You have a `factor` probably. They are `numeric` representations of categories, but you can't do maths on them. E.g. What is the mean of `factor(c("male","female"))` ? Makes no sense. Try `sapply(Test, class)`

Comment: @thelatemail It gets the same error with numeric columns `df1 <- data.frame(1:10); mean(df1)
#[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(df1) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Comment: @akrun-  I have 3 columns of data, and when I tried `colMeans(Test)` it returned: _Error in colMeans(Test) : 'x' must be numeric_.

Comment: It is because you don't have all the columns as numeric.  Some columns might be factor or character class.

Comment: @Rhertel: when trying `mean(as.matrix(Test))` the following is returned:     [1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(as.matrix(Test)) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: @akrun: But when I tested with sapply(Test, mode) it shows up as numeric under all 3 column labels

Comment: @thelatemail: When I tried: sapply(Test, class), it returned "numeric" under all three column names.

Comment: What does `dput(head(Test,1))` show? That will solve this once and for all.

Comment: @thelatemail: When I entered dput(head(Test,1)), it returned: structure(list(Xa = 0.68, b = 0.68, 
    c = 0.68), .Names = c("Xa", 
"b", "c"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

Comment: Based on the `dput`, `colMeans` should work fine

Comment: @akrun: I tried colMeans(Test) carefully and it returns the word NA under each column heading (like this):                                                                                                                  Xa         b       c
                  NA                   NA                   NA

Comment: Three columns with 20 data points is a small set. Why don't you copy the entire output of `dput(Test)` in your post?

Comment: As you said, there are some `NA` values in your dataset, therefore its probably better to use `colMeans(Test, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @Rhertel: Ok I tried dput(Test) & it returned: `structure(list(Xa = c(0.68, 0.28, 0.62, 0.73, 
3, 4, 5, 2.3, 2.6, 1.02, 2.33, 87, 0.62, 1.0, 1.48, 1.01, 1.0, 
6.01, 1.37), b = c(0.68, .28, 0.62, 0.73, 1.9, 1.5, 0.13, 
8.6, 0.12, 1.5, 0.18, 0.18, 0.07, 1.0, 1.0, 0.17, 1.0, 1.0, 0.1), c = c(0.68, 
0.28, 0.62, 0.73, 5, 3.2, 1.7, 2.1, 1.9, 0.9, 3.7, 2.3, 0.13, 1.0, 
0.32, 0.12, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)), .Names = c("Xa", 
"b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))` (Also by the way I added a dummy value in to the empty data space in my initial text to see if that helped)

Comment: Based on the `dput` , I get `colMeans(Test)#
      Xa        b        c 
6.423684 1.092632 1.456842`.  As @Jaap mentioned, there might be 'NA' values in your full dataset.  So, you can use `na.rm=TRUE`

Comment: Thank you. Using your data from the `dput` output I can't reproduce the error. Both `colMeans(Test)` and `mean(as.matrix(Test))` work without producing an error message. But the data contains only 19 points, and not 20 as stated in the OP.

Comment: @Japp: yes when I tried:  colMeans(Test, na.rm=TRUE) it does return results without any warnings. Will this work to add the mean into a boxplot? And if so, is it called separately after making the boxplot(Test)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to create a boxplot out of three numeric variables and add points with the mean for each of them.

```
#Create example data, including some NA values
set.seed(13121)
test = data.frame(a = c(rnorm(99, 1, 1), NA), 
                  b = c(NA, rnorm(99, 0, 1)), 
                  c = rnorm(100, 2, 2))


#Calculate means for each of the columns
means = colMeans(test)
```

The result in this case returns `NA` for the first two columns, because there are `NA` values in them:

```
means
#       a        b        c 
#      NA       NA 2.021736
```

The solution is to add `na.rm = TRUE` option (see `?colMeans` for more information):

```
means = colMeans(test, na.rm = TRUE)
means
#         a          b          c 
# 0.9843446 -0.1428516  2.0217361
```

Now we are ready to do the boxplot and add points with calculated means:

```
boxplot(test)
points(means, col = "red")
```

Result:

[image: boxplot example]

Comment: Thank you, this worked! However when I re-did this with longer names (i.e. 14 characters long) & added several variables, the plot either only showed every other name (if horizontal) or cut of some of the letters (if vertical, using `las=2'). The axis title also overlaps with the labels. Although `cex.axis` reduces the font, it is too small for my purpose. Is there a way to keep the entire axis name at the normal size  (`cex.axis=1) and not lose some of the letters in the 14 character name? thank you again.

Comment: @Ameno: For the problem of your labels being cut, you can adjust the size of the plot's margins with `par`, before doing the boxplot. For example: `par(mar = c(10, 4, 4, 2))`. Try different numbers to see what's best for you and see `?par` for more information. For the axis title, don't use `xlab` in the boxplot function and instead use `mtext` after drawing the boxplot. For example: `mtext(text = "x title", side = 1, padj = 14)`. Again, play with the `padj` parameter. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286473/rotating-x-axis-labels-in-r-for-barplot) for more information.

Comment: Thank you @hugo, all this helped and I'm trying different things to see what works. Your input has been very helpful, so I wanted to ask if there is a way to control the number of decimals or sig figs on the boxplot axis? I haven't been able to achieve this yet.