# Display column names in bar plot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am recently introduced in R. I am trying to create a bar plot from a data frame with 51 variable names just like the following example:

[image]

By using the `barplot` function I produced the following bar plot. Is there a way to display the variable names on the x-axis just like the above example:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286473/rotating-x-axis-labels-in-r-for-barplot

Comment: See this.  I think you are looking to use las


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286473/rotating-x-axis-labels-in-r-for-barplot

Comment: Yes indeed las worked fine, Thanks a lot for that. Although not the the variable names are not clearly shown as their length is too long.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with `cex.names` argument of `barplot` function.
`cex.names` determines the size for `x` labels, try to write `0.1` then increase by `0.1` to check for optimal size.
For example:

```
barplot(x,names.arg = x_name,cex.names=0.4)
```